# Bash - Move last word in line to beginning of line

Tags: linux, bash

I need to move (in a text file) the last word on a line to the beginning of that line.

From This:

```
I Am Legend (2007)
RoboCop (1987)
Shrek (2001)
```

To This:

```
(2007) I Am Legend
(1987) RoboCop
(2001) Shrek
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\((.*)\)/\2 \1/' file
```

Output:

```
(2007) I Am Legend 
(1987) RoboCop 
(2001) Shrek
```

To edit file "in place":

```
sed -i 's/\(.*\)\((.*)\)/\2 \1/' file
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk '{l=$NF;$NF=NF-1;print l,$0}' input.file
```

I'm storing the last word in the variable `l`, then decrease the field count by 1 (yes, this is possible) and then print the last word plus the remaining line.